# There is no SSMSEE on my SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

After I install or should I say after change it to 2008(Previous Version SQL Server 2005) there's no SSMSEE even though I did what the step for installing it. There's no SSMSEE 2008 in my SQL Server 2008 but of the video I watched there is. This is the link of screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFd4f.jpg

Please help me guys

Comment: There is no SQL Server 2008 actually - the earliest supported version is 2012. Management Studio is available in all versions. In 2016 it became a a [separate free download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) that supports all versions from SQL Server  2008 upwards

Comment: BTW why did you install an unsupported SQL Server version? The latest version, 2016 SP1 includes Enterprise-level features even in the Express and LocalDB editions like partitioning, encryption, compression, in-memory tables

Comment: Well I'm currently using SQL Server 2005 and just a little curious and the same time my school using SQL Server 2008 so I try to change it into SQL Server 2008..

Comment: SQL Server 2016 Developer edition is free and has all the features of Enterprise. There'se a huge difference between the versions - it's been 10 years after all

Comment: Well yeah, it just happen I'm working a system and my database is SQL Server 2005 based and the SQL Server 2008 only compatible of that database.